# How to get specific string value

Tags: r, regex

How to return value from string after some first character or number.

I have string like.

```
Test <- "Sample .first.second#"
```

my expected result will be.

```
Test <- "first.second#"
```

Note: How to remove before the `.string` value.

Comment: Do you refer this? `sub('Sample .', '', Test)` or you have several strings? can you provide a better example?

Comment: Thanks for response,But I don't want to hardcode  'Sample .',Because I"m  getting Test value from DB.

Comment: If so, then post an example of your data.

Comment: This should do the trick: `gsub("^.*?\\.","", Test)`

Comment: Space character before `.`, is it on purpose or a typo?

Comment: @Therkel,Thanks Its working as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub(pattern = "^.*?\\.",
     replacement = "",
     x = Test)
```

- `Pattern`: Match at the beginning of the line (`^`) any character (`.`) 0 more times (but the fewest number of times possible) (`*?`) in front of a period `\\.`
- `Replacement`: and replace the match by an empy string `""`
- `x`: from the input `Test`

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help

```
 > strsplit(Test, " .")[[1]][2]
 [1] "first.second# "
```

Comment: Problem with this method is that you assume that there is a space before the first period.